# Error: JsController could not be found

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I am using a Js link helper, which generate my javascript which is supposed to add my product to cart.

The problem is that i can't add to my cart and i can't access my generated (eg `/js/3d127cf10a9888fab50a67854c038a06.js`) javascript file.

If i try clicking the link in my source, the error: `'Error: JsController could not be found'` is thrown. I can't even find the generated file on my server.

I have tried adding the `prototype.js` and `scriptaculous.js` files together in my `/app/webroot/js` folder but all to no avail!.

Any working answer to this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: one possible thing is file with that name is not exists.

Comment: just don't know why even though my write enabled is on, on my ubuntu server. Just confuse

Comment: if you want to check that you can write files or not use this.file_put_contents('filepath','sometext'); try to add a file to js folder.

Comment: Yeah I have seen the generated file but its not responding to my click event when i click the 'add to cart' js->link. I checked my web console and saw the error '$(document).ready is not a function' could that be the reason its not responding??? thanks for your time!

Comment: I cant say anything without seeing any code. but you should use it like this. `$(document).ready(function(){alert('d');});`

Comment: Check the permissions on the file itself.  Open it up all the way and try, then back it down as you need.