# CakePHP JsController could not be found.

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, httpd.conf

When trying to access Javascript files from the webroot, I get the following error:

```
Missing Controller
Error:

JsController could not be found.
Error:

Create the class JsController below in file: app\Controller\JsController.php

<?php
  class JsController extends AppController {

  }
?>
```

I'm running without .htaccess files. Here is my configuration:

```
Listen 9090

<Directory "c:/wamp/apscmdb/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride none

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\apscmdb"

    <Directory "c:/wamp/apscmdb/">
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /app/webroot
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying the following code:
`echo $this->Html->script('portal');`

Which outputs:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/portal.js"></script>`

I found this that sounds similar, but no solution has been provided:
[Error: JsController could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038457/error-jscontroller-could-not-be-found)

Comment: You are on localhost or live server?

Comment: @FazalRasel ATM, its local development yes... using WAMP.

Comment: You have to use .htaccess file inside app directory

Comment: @Anubhav I'm trying to replicate this without the use of .htaccess files as they're not available in my production environments.

Comment: See /js/portal.js will always look for controller without .htaccess so you can change HTML helper so that it will create different path for js and css files

Comment: @Anubhav funny enough, if I add app/webroot/js/portal.js, they resolve just fine. I could modify the helper to output that path?

Comment: @Anubhav Did you want to provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @No my agenda is help, nothing else!

Comment: put this App::uses('AppController', 'Controller'); on top of your controller and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. Either use .htaccess files
2. Or modify the HTML helper to output the appropriate URLs for webroot